# Uniform distribution of array data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, and I would like to translate it into a uniform position, what would be the output get: `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`. The array is not always of such length and the numbers in it can be in different proportions to each other, so the question arises how to do it dynamically and not manually?

Need help

Comment: Can you provide a few more examples ? How should your final result look like in case of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
counters = {}
for element in arr:
    counters[element] = counters.get(element, 0) + 1
frequences = {k:len(arr)/float(v) for (k,v) in counters.items()}

progress = {k:0.0 for (k,v) in counters.items()}
result = []

for upperBound in range(len(arr)):
    partial_result = {}
    for (k,frequence) in frequences.items():
        if(frequence * progress[k] < float(upperBound) + 0.5):
            progress[k] = progress[k] + 1
            partial_result[k] = frequence * progress[k] - float(upperBound)
    for (k,v) in sorted(partial_result.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
        result.append(k)

print(result)
```

First getting frequencies for each number, then going from `1` to `len(arr)` checking if accumulated frequency for each number is below this threshold, if so output this number and accumulate its frequency further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question right. Is this code what you're looking for?

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

for e,i in enumerate(a):                        #finding the place where pattern is changed
    if i!=a[0]:
        divier_idx = e
        break

result=[]
for i in zip(a[divier_idx:],a[:divier_idx]):    #grouping data into needed formation 
    result.extend(i)

if len(a[divier_idx:]) != len(a[:divier_idx]):  #in case if the sec part is longer than the first one by 1 item it is appended to the end
    result.append(a[-1])

print(result)
# the output: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: because the lists are different sizes, you lost an item when zipping

Comment: @bn_ln you're right, I just don't understand how 'uniform position' should be specified. is that lost item (or even items in some cases) needed to be add to the end? we need OP to answer the question in comments.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

```
my_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

def make_uniform_list(the_list):
    my_set = list(set(the_list))
    size = len(the_list)/len(my_set)
    new_list = []
    for i in range(round(size)):
        new_list += my_set
    return new_list
```

## Examples:

```
ex_1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(make_uniform_list(ex_1))
#  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

ex_2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
print(make_uniform_list(ex_2))
#  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

ex_3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
print(make_uniform_list(ex_3))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: your code returns `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` but OP asks for `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` with `1` in the beginning

Comment: but the question is not clear enough, what if there are other numbers other than 1 and 0 ?